# How to calibrate an inclined MPU 6050 on Arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, mpu6050

I'm trying to use the MPU 6050 sensor (gyroscope + accelerometer) with my Arduino UNO to get some data when walking, running and making some other moves while carrying it. The problem is that my welding makes the sensor stay inclined. The first photo is from the sensor and the second from the 3-D visualization using the Processing IDE:

[image: Sensor inclined on the breadboard]

[image: The 3-D model]

Is there a way to calibrate the sensor to "act as if it were straight" based on its reads when inclined on the breadboard (as shown in the photo)? I am still a beginner with Arduino, so sorry if this is a silly question/problem.

Comment: Can you show us the sketch you're using?

Comment: your question is not about the Arduino ... it is about a Processing program ... just subtract the tilt before displaying the data